# How do I update DPKG itself on Debian? 

Tags: apache, debian, dpkg, mod-pagespeed

I have a very old version of it and it refuses to install new .deb files

This is the original problem:

Trying to install Google's mod_pagespeed for Apache.

Result:

> dpkg: regarding
>   mod-pagespeed-beta_current_i386.deb
>   containing mod-pagespeed-beta,
>   pre-dependency problem:
>   mod-pagespeed-beta pre-depends on dpkg
>   (>= 1.14.0) dpkg is installed, but is
>   version 1.13.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the .deb for `dpkg` and install it (but you should really be doing it via `apt-get` or `aptitude`). Your problem is not that your version of `dpkg` would not install *anything*, but that the particular package requires being installed by newer version.

Comment: it seems the entire distro needs to get updated, dpkg is just the tip of the iceberg :(  thanks anyway

Comment: Which is ".deb for `dpkg`"?

Comment: @DjDac, The one called `dpkg_`*version*`_`*arch*`.dpkg`. The one that contains dpkg itself. Because dpkg is, of course, installed by dpkg too.

Answer (score 4):

`aptitude upgrade dpkg` or `apt-get install dpkg` if you don't have aptitude.

Edit: Correction from @Tshepang

Comment: The right commands are `aptitude|apt-get install dpkg`; Also `apt-get` was never depcrecated. There was a time when it was advised that people do major system upgrades using `aptitude`, but that was some time ago.

Comment: I wasn't aware that apt-get was not deprecated, it was what a colleague had told me, he will be shot promptly. If he already has dpkg in the system them upgrade will upgrade it. Tested on a debian system here -- but thanks for the down-vote :-)

Comment: You did not correct the `upgrade` command. It's wrong. It will upgrade the entire system instead of just `dpkg`.

Comment: People tend to inflate actual events. There was a whole movement to use aptitude instead of apt-get, because aptitude was so much better in many cases. It was never an official thing though, all except for the system upgrade thing. But apt-get has caught up with that part.

Comment: @Tshepang `aptitude upgrade dpkg` wants to upgrade `dpkg dpkg-dev`, `aptitude upgrade` wants to install about a bazillion packages. `apt-get upgrade dpkg` however wants to install about a bazillion packages. I was correct for aptitude but not for apt-get. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Interesting than. But why not just keep it consistent. You are going to be confusing people. In Debian, `install` also implies `upgrade`.

Comment: I chose it use `upgrade` instead of `install` as while `install` implies `upgrade`, `upgrade` does not imply `install`. e.g. My machine does not have `lighttpd` -- `aptitude install lighthttpd` would install it whereas `aptitude upgrade lighttpd` would do nothing